# How to access child components in parent component?

Tags: angular

I have a Angular2 template like this:

```
     <app-tab [Title]="'Test1'">
        <app-component-one></app-component-one>
     </app-tab>

     <app-tab [Title]="'Test2'">
        <app-component-two></app-component-two>
     </app-tab>
```

Now, how can I access the `app-component-one` or  `app-component-two` in `app-tab`?

The output from app-tab should be something like this:

```
<div>
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1 class="panel-title">Test 1</h1>
    <div>CONTENT FROM app-component-one</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Use @ViewChild(AppComponentOne) and access it in ngAfterViewInit. Like this: http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681. `@ContentChild()` is probably what you want.

Comment: In @ContentChildren(SomeType) contentChildren; 
But I don't want to specify a component like `app-component-one` or `app-component-two` in SomeType. Is there a way to do it?